# How to expand the Regex to actual values

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for Opensource Java library which could help me in expanding all the possible values out of Numeric Regex, for example: if I give a range 1234[7-9] as input, it should output 12347,12348, 12349, similarly taking care of 123[4-6][7-9], which would translate to 12347, 12357, 12367 so on. Instead of reinventing wheel I would like to know if there are any libraries which could do this. This is only for Numeric regex with defined range.

Comment: You assuming that people who downvote without comment are not sensible? Why?

Comment: Yes, how else will I know why was it downvoted and how to improve/correct ?

Comment: You can read rules.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." say the rules. That's why people downvote

Comment: Thanks for you comment, it helps!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have once tried out [Xeger](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nl.flotsam/xeger/1.0.0-lorislab-1) which was good enough for such simple expressions similar to yours above. You will also need [automaton jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dk.brics.automaton/automaton/1.11-8) package, that you can download as a library in order to use Xeger.

Example how to use:

```
    String regex = "123[4-6][7-9]"; 
    Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
    Set<String> generated = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        generated.add(generator.generate());
    }
    System.out.println(generated);

    //[12367, 12348, 12359, 12349, 12357, 12368, 12369, 12347, 12358]
```